# Is "through" the most natural word to use here?

Tags: prepositions

I would like to know if **through** is the best word to use in these sentences or maybe **in** is better?

> Robert drives **through** the city. He parks outside a building and gets out of the car.
>
> Robert walks **through** a cemetery. He stops by his brothers grave.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on what was actually happening, as well as Robert's intention, but it sounds like it could be:

> Robert drives **into** the city. He parks outside a building and gets out of the car.

I wouldn't say "through" as it sounds like Robert did not go all the way through the city (and out of the other side).

> Robert walks **into** a cemetery. He stops by his brother’s grave.

The same reasoning applies here.

**Update following provision of context**

"Through" would be fine if we already know Robert is in the city/cemetery, or if we know that he is intending to stop somewhere in the city/cemetery.

Otherwise we must establish that fact:

> Robert **is driving through** the city. He parks outside a building and gets out of the car.
>
> Robert **is walking through** a cemetery. He stops by his brother’s grave.

Comment: In both sentences Robert is already in the city and in the cemetery, so the meaning is more like: Robert is driving through the city and Robert is walking through a cemetery

Comment: Ok, thanks - see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, Chris.

Comment: The grave is either **his brother's** or **his brothers'**. It is not **his brothers grave**. Apostrophe required!

Comment: No problem, please mark the answer as correct if it is so. :)

Comment: Well spotted, Robert - thank you!